# Groupby month and year pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I extract from date(e.g. 2020-11-19) to separe column year and month.
Now i need group by "Celkem" to month. When i use sum() i have a problem that it also counts a year as column "Celkom"
On each line need to have year for row in sql.

```
          Celkem  year  month
11     17.47  2020     11
19    305.10  2020     11
22   1197.50  2020     11
23   1848.10  2020     10
..       ...   ...    ...
288   369.59  2017     10
289    47.00  2017     10
290   277.00  2017     10
```

Expact:

```
1     1520.07  2020     11
2     1848.10  2020     10
3     .......  2020     9
4     .......  2020     8
```

Comment: Do you need `df.groupby('month')['Celkem'].sum()` ?

Comment: Not working make same df as without this.

Comment: Make sum of "Celkem" by month. I try df_data.groupby(['month','year'])['Celkem'].sum().reset_index() / df_data.set_index(['year','month']).sum(level=[0,1]) / df_data.groupby(['year', 'month']).agg({'Celkem': "sum"})

Comment: 1     1520.07  2020     11 / 
2     1848.10  2020     10

Comment: Super, so `df = df.groupby(['month','year'], sort=False)['Celkem'].sum().reset_index()` working for me perfectly, for you not?

Comment: Also why is division there `/ df_data.set_index(['year','month']).sum(level=[0,1]) / df_data.groupby(['year', 'month']).agg({'Celkem': "sum"})` ?

Comment: I try what i find on stackoverflow but no group by month

Comment: Sorry with df = df.groupby(['month','year'], sort=False)['Celkem'].sum().reset_index() this work perfect.

Comment: Na Slovensko len excel tabulka je z Ceskeho softwareu.

Comment: Tak este lepsie, ;)